# Ikvmc doesn't find main in NetBeans produced .jar

Tags: java, netbeans, ikvm

I have created a .jar from NetBeans and now I am trying to convert it to .NET (using http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/tutorial.html as tutorial).

Ikvmc gives me that error:

`warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Counters/AtomicCounter.class", including it as resource  (class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Counters/CharCounter.class", including it as resource (class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Counters/Thread.class", including it as resource (class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "File/FileController.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$1.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$10.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$2.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$3.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$4.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$5.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$6.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$7.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$8.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame$9.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Gui/MainFrame.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "ListElement/ListObject.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Performance/RamSample.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Performance/RamSpectator.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "Performance/TimeKeeper.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "threadtester/ThreadTester$1.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "threadtester/ThreadTester.class", including it as resource(class format error "52.0")
note IKVMC0004: Using main class "threadtester.ThreadTester" based on jar manifest
note IKVMC0002: Output file is "ThreadTester.exe"
fatal error IKVMC5033: Main class not found`

The netbens manifest is correct.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 11):

I found that the version I used was old. For java 8 use this version of ikvm http://www.frijters.net/ikvmbin-8.1.5717.0.zip